# Partial string matching in PHP

Tags: php, match

```
$var1 = 'accommodation_rate_fri_to_sun_garden_view';
$var2 = 'Garden View';

if (  stripos($var1, $var2) !== false ) {
    echo 'found';
}
else {
    echo 'not found';
}
```

// result is `not found`. Is there any other function for patial matching?

Comment: The result is not found because Garden View is not in the $var1 variable. I am pretty sure that there is no function that can do something like this. Strpos would only give you a result of true if the exact text is found in the string.

Comment: I understand, thats why I need idea on partial matching. Is there any way I could compare with the first word of a string only?

Comment: Yes you could use the explode function like this. $arr = explode(' ',$var2);

if(strpos($var1, $arr[0]) { gives true if Garden is found }

Comment: I know about explode, buts it not elegant. Also, this is not a variable but a value of an array, I just posted it as such for readability.

Comment: I don't think there is any other way around it man. You could add this functionality in a function  yourself and then call it in your actual script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
$var1 = 'accommodation_rate_fri_to_sun_garden_view';
$var2 = 'Garden View';
$var2 = str_replace(" ", "_", strtolower($var2));
if (  stripos($var1, $var2) !== false ) {
    echo 'found';
}
else {
    echo 'not found';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$haystack = 'accommodation_rate_fri_to_sun_garden_view';
$needle   = 'Garden View';
$needles  = explode(' ', $needle);
$partial  = false;

foreach($needles as $needle)
{
    if(stripos($haystack, $needle) !== false)
    {
        $partial = true;
        break;
    }
}

if($partial)
{
    echo 'found';
}
else
{
    echo 'not found';
}
```